# using simple timers in ROS - doesn't show up in rqt

Tags: timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on ROS Hydro (with Catkin). I made a node with a C++ timer, with the following code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int args,char* argv[])
{
 clock_t startTime = clock(); //Start timer
 double secondsPassed;
 
 bool flag = true;
 while(flag)
  {
   secondsPassed = (clock() - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   if(secondsPassed >= 120)
    {
     std::cout << "Hello ROS, this is a C++ node and " << secondsPassed << " seconds have passed" << std::endl;
     flag = false;
    }
  }
}
```

This works just fine ! but the funny part is that it doesn't show up on rqt. If the node is running for 120 seconds, it should register in rqt for those 120 seconds - which it doesn't ! Any hints ? explanation ? or am I doing something wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175170/using-simple-timers-in-ros---doesn%27t-show-up-in-rqt/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add these lines in the first of your program:

```
 /**
   * The ros::init() function needs to see argc and argv so that it can perform
   * any ROS arguments and name remapping that were provided at the command line. For programmatic
   * remappings you can use a different version of init() which takes remappings
   * directly, but for most command-line programs, passing argc and argv is the easiest
   * way to do it.  The third argument to init() is the name of the node.
   *
   * You must call one of the versions of ros::init() before using any other
   * part of the ROS system.
   */
  ros::init(argc, argv, "Timer");

  /**
   * NodeHandle is the main access point to communications with the ROS system.
   * The first NodeHandle constructed will fully initialize this node, and the last
   * NodeHandle destructed will close down the node.
   */
  ros::NodeHandle n;
```

and also you nee incude:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1